# Returning parent by Parsing JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

What will be Javascript code look like in following scenario?
I have following json object.

```
  jsonObject=  '{
     "2lor": {"userID":"1","clientID":"abc123","uid":"j42d"},
     "WFAR": {"userID":"2","clientID":"xyz123","uid":"V23d"}
    }'
```

I want to parse above json. I want to return

```
"2lor": {"userID":"1","clientID":"abc123","uid":"j42d"}
```

when my parameter is `"j42d"`.

My function will be look like this one.

```
function Find(uid, done) {

  return done(null, value);
};
```

uid: "j42d",
value(output):

```
"2lor": {"userID":"1","clientID":"abc123","uid":"j42d"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop over your JSON object and find the values that fit your criteria.

And Pamblam is right, you need to either get rid of the linebreaks in your string, or build your JSON as an object literal:

```
var json = {  
  "2lor":{  
    "userID":"1",
    "clientID":"abc123",
    "uid":"j42d"
  },
  "WFAR":{  
    "userID":"2",
    "clientID":"xyz123",
    "uid":"V23d"
  }
};
var myResult = getByUid(json, "j42d");

function getByUid(data, uid) {
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && data[key].uid === uid) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[key] = data[key];
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var json_string = '{ "2lor": {"userID":"1","clientID":"abc123","uid":"j42d"}, "WFAR": {"userID":"2","clientID":"xyz123","uid":"V23d"} }';
var json = JSON.parse(json_string);
var data = json['2lor'];

// to get the uid..
var uid = data.uid;
```

Note, you can't have linebreaks in javascript strings unless you escape them, so you will need to put that all on one line (or just remove the outer quotes and skip the parsing).

Comment: my function parameter is uid, i want to return parent json. I have uid. i don't have '2lor'

Comment: @LutforRahman - Your question doesn't say anything about a function. Even if it did, I have no idea what you're doing with it or how it's relevant.

Comment: I Edited the question.

Comment: @LutforRahman make a jsfiddle. i'm not going to write your function for you. you try something and we'll help fix it.